# html meta tags not inherited in frameset's parent

Tags: html, namecheap, noip

I'm trying to make a webpage responsive which, by itself, works, but namecheap (which redirects to hopto ([no-ip.com](http://no-ip.com))), embeds everything in a `frameset`:

```
<frameset rows="100%, *" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" border="0">
        <frame src="http://kmouratidis.hopto.org:8081/" name="mainwindow" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    </frameset>
```

which in turn means that the inner meta tag for checking viewport doesn't affect the outer frame. I'm pretty sure this is the intended behavior, I just want a suggestion as to how to solve this.

---

Printscreen (sorry, can't get `view page source` and `view frame source` to work well together) of what the whole code looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control the HTML generated by your domain masking service.

You can't manipulate the DOM of that document later.

So: Get real domain hosting instead of using a masking service.

No-ip.com will [provide that service](https://www.noip.com/members/registration/transfer.php?page=step1).

Comment: Is this something javascript could potentiall solve? If not, can it be solved by joining the two services (ddns + hosting) anywhere (e.g. configuring ddns in namecheap instead of transfering the domain)?

Comment: "Is this something javascript could potentiall solve?" — No, that's why I said you can't manipulate the DOM of that document later. Cross-origin security prevents it.

Comment: "e.g. configuring ddns in namecheap instead of transfering the domain" — If name cheap offer a DDNS service, then sure.